# how to create shapes drawing a diagram

Tags: mxgraph, draw.io

I'm new to draw.io and mgraphx. I know how to create a shape 'programmatically' in draw.io using 'extras/create shape'

I'm wondering if it is possible to drag some basic shape to a diagram, 'merge' them to a single shape, then add some connection point and finally drag the new shape to a library.

I tried grouping the basic shapes but a group is not a shape in itself (it cannot have connections points, and it cannot be connected to other shapes, only the contained shapes can).

Is there a way to create a new shape 'diagrammatically' from basic shapes?
if not, ther are some examples that show how to do the merge of basic shapes using the mxgraph library ?

thankyou